# MEX fortran file using Gnumex and MinGW (g77)

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex, fortran77

There is a problem that I ran into recently. It used to be working fine as far as I remember but after a few week I am trying again to MEX a fortran 77 file in MATLAB but it is giving me a weird error.
Ok, I made the MEX options file using Gnumex which is named `mexopts_f77.bat`.
This is the command that I run in MATLAB:

`mex -v -f C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\mexopts_f77.bat -c sodex.f decsol.f`

And this is the the error that I get:

```
-> Options file specified on command line 
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
->    Options file           = C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\mexopts_f77.bat 
      MATLAB                 = C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011b 
->    COMPILER               = gcc 
->    Compiler flags: 
         COMPFLAGS           = -c -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -fcase-upper -fnounderscoring 
         OPTIMFLAGS          = -O0 
         DEBUGFLAGS          = -g 
         arguments           =  
         Name switch         = -o 
->    Pre-linking commands   =  
->    LINKER                 = C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011b\sys\perl\win32\bin\perl.exe C:\omid\other\gnumex\linkmex.pl 
->    Link directives: 
         LINKFLAGS           =  -LC:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs 
         LINKDEBUGFLAGS      = -g  -Wl,--image-base,0x28000000\n 
         LINKFLAGSPOST       =  
         Name directive      = -o sodex.mexw32 
         File link directive =  
         Lib. link directive =  
         Rsp file indicator  =  
->    Resource Compiler      = C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011b\sys\perl\win32\bin\perl.exe C:\omid\other\gnumex\rccompile.pl  -o mexversion.res 
->    Resource Linker        =  
----------------------------------------------------------------


--> gcc  -c -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -fcase-upper -fno-underscoring -osodex.obj -O0 -DMX_COMPAT_32 sodex.f 

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fcase-upper' 

  C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'sodex.f' failed.
```

I think the problem is with `-fcase-upper` option. I looked it up but could not find any information regrading that option for `gcc`.

## Edit:

I manually changed `gcc` to `g77` in my options file and was successful to create the object files but still getting an error in the final step where I try to link the object files to the main fortran script named `vdpsodex.F` and create the MEX file. As requested, I am including the option file:

```
@echo off
rem C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\mexopts_f77.bat
rem Generated by gnumex.m script in C:\omid\other\gnumex
rem gnumex version: 2.06
rem Compile and link options used for building MEX etc files with
rem the Mingw/Cygwin tools.  Options here are:
rem Gnumex, version 2.06                     
rem MinGW linking                            
rem Mex (*.dll) creation                     
rem Libraries regenerated now                
rem Language: Fortran 77                     
rem Optimization level: -O0 (no optimization)
rem StorageVersion: 1.0
rem C++keyName: GNU C++
rem C++keyManufacturer: GNU
rem C++keyLanguage: C++
rem C++keyVersion:
rem C++keyFileName: GNUMEXOPTS.bat
rem Matlab version 7.13
rem
set GCCINSTALLDIR=C:\Omid\Other\MinGW\bin
set MATLAB=C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011b
set GM_PERLPATH=C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011b\sys\perl\win32\bin\perl.exe
set GM_UTIL_PATH=C:\omid\other\gnumex
set PATH=C:\Omid\Other\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Cygwin\usr\local\gfortran\libexec\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.3.0
set LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Omid\Other\MinGW\lib
set G95_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Omid\Other\MinGW\lib
set MW_TARGET_ARCH=win32
rem
rem precompiled library directory and library files
set GM_QLIB_NAME=C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs
rem
rem directory for .def-files
set GM_DEF_PATH=C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs
rem
rem Type of file to compile (mex or engine)
set GM_MEXTYPE=mex
rem
rem Language for compilation
set GM_MEXLANG=f77
rem
rem File for exporting mexFunction symbol
set GM_MEXDEF=C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs\fmex.def
rem
set GM_ADD_LIBS=-lg2c -lflibmx -lflibmex -lflibmat
rem
rem compiler options; add compiler flags to compflags as desired
set NAME_OBJECT=-o
rem ************ This is where I replaced gcc with g77 ************
set COMPILER=g77
rem ***************************************************************
set COMPFLAGS=-c -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -fcase-upper -fno-underscoring 
set OPTIMFLAGS=-O0
set DEBUGFLAGS=-g
rem
rem NB Library creation commands occur in linker scripts
rem but LIBLOC is provided for compatibility with
rem mex.getCompilerConfigurations
rem
rem Linker parameters
set LIBLOC=
set LINKER=%GM_PERLPATH% %GM_UTIL_PATH%\linkmex.pl
set LINKFLAGS=
set LINKOPTIMFLAGS=-s
set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=-g  -Wl,--image-base,0x28000000\n
set LINKFLAGS= -LC:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs
set LINK_FILE=
set LINK_LIB=
set NAME_OUTPUT=-o %OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%.mexw32
rem
rem Resource compiler parameters
set RC_COMPILER=%GM_PERLPATH% %GM_UTIL_PATH%\rccompile.pl  -o %OUTDIR%mexversion.res
set RC_LINKER=
```

Now the above code does give me the object files but when I try to make the final MEX file using below command:

```
mex -v -f C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\mexopts_f77.bat vdpsodex.F sodex.obj decsol.obj
```

it gives me the following error:

```
-> Options file specified on command line 
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
->    Options file           = C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\mexopts_f77.bat 
      MATLAB                 = C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011b 
->    COMPILER               = g77 
->    Compiler flags: 
         COMPFLAGS           = -c -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -fcase-upper -fno-underscoring 
         OPTIMFLAGS          = -O0 
         DEBUGFLAGS          = -g 
         arguments           =  
         Name switch         = -o 
->    Pre-linking commands   =  
->    LINKER                 = C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011b\sys\perl\win32\bin\perl.exe C:\omid\other\gnumex\linkmex.pl 
->    Link directives: 
         LINKFLAGS           =  -LC:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs 
         LINKDEBUGFLAGS      = -g  -Wl,--image-base,0x28000000\n 
         LINKFLAGSPOST       =  
         Name directive      = -o vdpsodex.mexw32 
         File link directive =  
         Lib. link directive =  
         Rsp file indicator  =  
->    Resource Compiler      = C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011b\sys\perl\win32\bin\perl.exe C:\omid\other\gnumex\rccompile.pl  -o mexversion.res 
->    Resource Linker        =  
---------------------------------------------------------------- 


--> g77  -c -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -fcase-upper -fno-underscoring -oC:\Users\GHASEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_7FJjxb\vdpsodex.obj -O0 -DMX_COMPAT_32 vdpsodex.F 


--> C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011b\sys\perl\win32\bin\perl.exe C:\omid\other\gnumex\linkmex.pl -o vdpsodex.mexw32  -LC:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs -s  C:\Users\GHASEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_7FJjxb\vdpsodex.obj  sodex.obj  decsol.obj   

C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs/flibmx.lib(ds00068.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__Omid_Other_Gnumex_libs_flibmx_lib' 
C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs/flibmx.lib(ds00086.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__Omid_Other_Gnumex_libs_flibmx_lib' 
C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs/flibmx.lib(ds00062.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__Omid_Other_Gnumex_libs_flibmx_lib' 
C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs/flibmx.lib(ds00157.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__Omid_Other_Gnumex_libs_flibmx_lib' 
C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs/flibmx.lib(ds00161.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__Omid_Other_Gnumex_libs_flibmx_lib' 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
link command: g77 -shared C:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs\fmex.def -o vdpsodex.mexw32 -LC:\Omid\Other\Gnumex\libs -s C:\Users\GHASEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_7FJjxb\vdpsodex.obj sodex.obj decsol.obj -lg2c -lflibmx -lflibmex -lflibmat 

  C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2011B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'vdpsodex.mexw32' failed.
```

Comment: oops, the fomatting is messed up. How do I edit the question?

Comment: Alright, now it looks much better but still not exactly what I expected.

Comment: Okay, it is now excatly the same as what it looks in my MATLAB command window. Well, let's see if anyone could pin point what the problem is.

Comment: `-fcase-upper` is a `g77` option and not recognized by `gfortran`. Do you need it? What happens if you just delete it? Fortran is case-insensitive...

Comment: My compiler is g77 as I mentioned in the title. But I cannot figure out why it keeps giving me the error even though the code is in fortran 77 syntax. When I remove that from the option file it says it does not recognize the created .obj file format.

Comment: What you have shown here is the output of `gcc`, not `g77`!

Comment: I made the option file `mexopts_f77.bat` using Gnumex and do not know why it uses gcc instead of g77. Have you worked with Gnumex before? You might be able to help me out. It seems that the option file that I made does not work as it is supposed to do.

Comment: I just edited the main post and added my options file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*emphasized text*Finally, I was able to pin point the issue and I thought it might be beneficial to others who may be facing the same issue (or similar to this one) to share the answer. Let me just mention that it was looking strange to me at the first place because I had MEX'ed the exact same files using an option files created by Gnumex and had not problem at all. I just noticed that because I changed my MinGW build a while ago I was not able to MEX the same Fortran files anymore even though I re-created the options file (`mexopts_f77.bat`).

Anyways, to make the long story short I found this [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnumex/mailman/message/31736176/) very useful. Basically, it suggests downloading five packages and extracting them to the root directory of MinGw. Four of those links are still alive. One of them is dead but I found it by Googling the package name. What you see below is the updated links of the packages.

Last but not least, here is the solution if your g77 is not working with a Gnumex-made options file:

1. Download following packages:

   - [binutils-2.19.1-mingw32-bin.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/binutils/binutils-2.19.1/binutils-2.19.1-mingw32-bin.tar.gz/download)
   - [gcc-core-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version3/Current%20Release_%20gcc-3.4.5-20060117-3/gcc-core-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz/download)
   - [gcc-g77-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version3/Current%20Release_%20gcc-3.4.5-20060117-3/gcc-g77-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz/download)
   - [mingw-runtime-3.14.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/)
   - [w32api-3.11.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/w32api/w32api-3.11/w32api-3.11.tar.gz/download)
2. Extract them to your MinGW root directory, e.g. `C:\MinGW`
3. Re-make your options file by selecting Fortran 77 as compilation language, e.g. `mexopt_f77.bat`
4. MEX you Fortran script using following syntax.

   > mex -f [*options-file*] [fortran-file.f]
5. If you need to link some files to the main script then you have to compile them first to object files and then link them.

   > mex -f [*options-file*] -c [*linkfile1.f*] [*linkfile2.f*]
   >
   > mex -f [*options-file*] [*fortran-file.f*] [*linkfile1.obj*] [*linkfile2.obj*]